# React Native - iOS App screen layout flickers when the active screen has ListItem in it

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-elements

I have a React Native app that uses `react-native-elements@1.0.0-beta5`. The app's screen layout start flickering and app turns unresponsive when I follow these steps:

1. Go to a page which has a `ListItem` component in it.
2. Pause the app by pressing the home button.
3. Resume the app using the icon or from the running app list.

This issue only happens in iOS devices.

**Things I already tried:**

1. Upgrade `react-native-elements` to latest stable version. It's currently `1.0.0`.
2. Disable header buttons in router (`react-navigation`).
3. Remove tab navigator from the app.

**Additional info:**

1. If I remove the `ListItem` component and use a simple `View` or a `Text` instead, the issue does not occur.
2. Issue occurs even if the `ListItem` is placed in the screen directory without a `List` or a `FlatList`.
3. App is using `react-native@0.55.3`. Upgrading to latest version is not possible at this time due to the breaking changes.

Has someone encountered similar issue or guide me in the right direction to find the root cause?

Comment: Did you identify the issue, I am facing the same problem?

Comment: @coolcake I've rewritten the ListItem using react hooks and upgraded react-native and react-native-elements to latest versions (at that time) and it was resolved. But I never found the actual root cause.